# Is it possible to write a UDF in VBA that contains a period in the name?

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

Excel 2010 ships with some functions that contain a period in their name. For example `STDEV.S` and `PERCENTILE.EXC`

Is it possible to assign a name to my own function with a name such as `PERCENTILE.CUSTOM` using VBA?

For example, I would like to reference the following function using the formula `=NAME.SUFFIX()`

```
Option Explicit

Function NAMEdotSUFFIX() As Variant

    NAMEdotSUFFIX = 42

End Function
```

Comment: Yes (sort of) - you can create a module named "name" and your function "suffix" would be contained in that module. In the sheet you can then use `=Name.Suffix()`

Comment: In VBA, you cannot have a UDF name with a DOT like in `STDEV.S` 

Having said that you can however create a VSTO solution where you can give that kind of name in ClickOnce installer.

Comment: Tim, could you put your answer as a 'proper' answer so that I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible from VBA. [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/sect4ck6.aspx) shows how to define a function in VBA, and specifically [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/81ed9a62.aspx) lays out the rules for element names.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as technically correct, according to the question. However please note Tim and Sid's comments, which offer practical solutions to work around this limitation

Answer (score 6):

As @SiddharthRout already suggested, external libraries have fewer restrictions than VBA when it comes to declaring function names, so periods are permitted in external names.

Despite the MSDN documentation, it *is* possible to use *some* special characters in VBA identifiers, including UDFs. The special characters can even be the *first/only* character in the identifier. The special characters will vary in their availability, according to the code-page of the VBA project and VBE.

This is a perfectly valid VBA function:

```
Public Function Foo·Bar()
  Foo·Bar = 5
End Function
```

And can be used in an Excel formula:

```
=Foo·Bar()
5
```

Likewise, this *gem* of a function uses a non-breaking space as *the* function name:

```
Public Function  ()
    = 6
End Function
```

But while the function with an NBSP is valid, sadly, it can't be used in an Excel formula.

It is possible to use:

```
Public Function ·()
  · = 5
End Function
```

**BONUS HACK**

Somebody forgot to tell the `Enum` team about the identifier rules. And while Enums can't be used in Excel formulas, you can use any character except a carriage return or square-brackets *inside* square brackets, as an enum name or member.

This is perfectly valid VBA:

```
Enum [Foo : Bar = 5 : End Enum]
  [.B!a r"] = 6
End Enum
```

And the VBE pretty-printer turns it into this unparseable mess:

```
Enum Foo : Bar = 5 : End Enum
  [.B!a r"] = 6
End Enum
```