# Excel User Defined Function with Qualified Names (e.g. BINOM.DIST)

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am playing around with creating simple DSLs in Excel, and would like to be able to create User Defined Functions of the form [Group].[UDF_Name], so one might type CellStory.Name(...) for example.

An example of what I am talking about is the [BINOM.DIST function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/binom-dist-function-HP010335671.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP010335634).

There is also an apparent example in ["The Quest for the Excel custom function tooltip"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903587/the-quest-for-the-excel-custom-function-tooltip) where the questioner uses ARe.Program.AddLayer(...).

My googling doesn't turn up anything, though not really sure what the best terms to search are.

And playing around defining UDFs in Worksheet, Workbook, Module, Class Modules, every way I can think too also doesn't give me anything.

??? )-:

Greatly appreciate advice anyone might be able to give on this. Thanks.

Comment: It does! Module.Function approach mentioned in the comments works and will serve my current purposes. I must have done something silly wrong when I tried this the other day, and my searches will have all had "full-stop" or "dot" in, "Period", "Period", "Period"... serious absently minded I'm afraid. Greatly appreciate the pointing, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per "me how"'s comment, this is a duplicate question, the answer that will do for me from the comments to [Is it possible to write a UDF in VBA that contains a period in the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041671/is-it-possible-to-write-a-udf-in-vba-that-conatins-a-period-in-the-name):

> Yes (sort of) - you can create a module named "name" and your function
>   "suffix" would be contained in that module. In the sheet you can then
>   use =Name.Suffix()

–  [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) Apr 16 '13 at 16:02

> In VBA, you cannot have a UDF name with a DOT like in STDEV.S Having
>   said that you can however create a VSTO solution where you can give
>   that kind of name in ClickOnce installer.

–  [Siddharth Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout)

Comment: vote to close your question as a duplicate instead of answering it.