# Is it possible to use a backslash `\` character in an Excel UDF?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, user-defined-functions, xll

I already answered a similar question here, about periods `.` in a name, but I'm unsure about whether the same rule holds for backslashes.

[Is it possible to write a UDF in VBA that contains a period in the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041671/is-it-possible-to-write-a-udf-in-vba-that-conatins-a-period-in-the-name/41884990#41884990)

If the UDF is written in an external library, will the library allow backslashes in function names, and will Excel allow me to use that function name in a worksheet formula? Will excel require me to escape the character in some way?

Or, perhaps a backslash is valid when used to escape another character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about an UDF created via the Excel C API (XLL based), it is possible.

You just need to register the name (argument `pxProcedure` in [xlfRegister](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687900(v=office.15).aspx))  with an escape character (i.e to register `My\Func` you employ `My\\Func`). Then you can call it directly from a cell without escaping the character.

See below (also with two backslashes) :

[image: TwoBackSlashExcel]

[[image: eBackSlashExcel[2]]

**Edit :** 
With a single backslash character :

[image: single]

Comment: Thanks. Will Excel permit the \ to be the *leading*, trailing, or *only* character, or is that moot, because the function will be preceded by `_xll.`?

Comment: Yes, I just tested it, it works for all cases (leading,trailing and only character).